# How do I use a loop to store values into a vector?

Tags: r, loops, vector

The vector needs to have 1000 values, and each value comes from taking the mean of a sample from a larger set of data. Here is my code:

```
xbar10 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  xbar10 <- mean(sample(X, 10))
}
```

I want to use a loop to store each new value from the `mean(sample(X, 10))` into my new vector `xbar10` but I'm having trouble getting it to store 100 values, it just returns one.

Comment: Define the length of xbar10: `xbar10 <- numeric(length=1000)` then to store use: `xbar[i]<-...`

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you! I made the edits you suggested and I have gotten what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `replicate`.

```
#Assuming X is something like this
X <- runif(100)
xbar10 <- replicate(1000, mean(sample(X, 10)))
xbar10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rerun`

```
library(purrr)
X <- runif(100)
xbar10 <- flatten_dbl(rerun(1000, mean(sample(X, 10))))
```